# Error in my Python Script editing a txt with a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm basically supposed to create a python script that reads a function from my file called "myfucntions.py" and have it construct a list of all of the punctuation characters. Then use a list method to remove the apostrophe character from that list. Have an input that asks for the file name to read and for each line in the file use string methods to make it all lower case and remove any leading or trailing white space.

I'm supposed to use my replace_chars function that I created in myfunctions with making everything lower case and removing white space, as well as removing the apostrophe character. Then finally display the modified line after using the replace_chars function, preceded by the line number using the string format method.

myfunctions.py:

```
def replace_chars(stringa, listb):
'''A function to return stringa by removing the list of characters from listb'''
    for x in listb:
        stringa = stringa.replace(x, ' ')
    return stringa
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import test
    test.testEqual(replace_chars(" SamplEam*",["p", "E", "*"]), " Sam l am ")
```

script I've got so far:

```
import myfunctions
import string

def main():

    punc = list(string.punctuation)
    punc.remove('\'')
    filename = input('Enter file name to read: ')
    line_num = 1
    with open( filename ) as z:
        for a in z.fileread: 
            a = a.lower()
            a = a.rstrip()
            a = lstrip()
            a = myfunctions.replace_chars(a,punc)
    print("{0}:{1}".format(line_num,a))
    line_num += 1
main()
```

My output is this Error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'fileread'
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find `fileread` as a method anywhere in python, let alone an attribute. Where did you find that?

Comment: _Don't_ edit all the content out of your question just because it was answered. That does not serve any purpose hanging around on the site and just makes the answer nonsensical. I've rolled back.

Comment: Please don't remove your entire question, mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted using the green tick instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it for you -- `fileread` is not an attribute of files in python. When you call `for a in z.fileread:` it fails because that isn't a thing. Probably what you were looking for is `z.readlines()`.

Comment: @Hatch If the answer worked for you, press the checkmark (accept button) under the answer so others don't answer this question again. Also keep the original text in your question so that others that might have the same question can find your question again.

Comment: My output is only reading the very last line of the file. Any idea why?

"Enter file name to read: princess.txt
1:grandfather oh  well  thank you very much  very nice of you  your vote of confidence is overwhelming  all right   puts glasses on   the princess bride  by s  morgenstern  chapter one  buttercup was raised on a small farm in the country of florin" is all I'm getting

Comment: @Hatch It's probably an issue of tabbing. Put your `print` statement inside the `for` loop so that it prints for every line. Since it's outside the loop, it will only print the last line read.

Comment: Thank you, I just now noticed it wasn't in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

i think you meant to read every line of the file as a list of strings:

```
for a in x.fileread
```

is wrong since file objects have no attribute fileread
the right way is to convert the file into list of strings with readlines method:

```
file = open(filname, 'r')
listofstrings = file.readlines()
```

then you can iterate through listofstrings

Comment: This just states exactly the same thing as the accepted answer from 16 mins earlier...

Comment: Minus the typo in the variable holding the file name.